# NavigationLink creates multiple instances of destinations in a List before selecting the row

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a List of contacts, and on clicking I want to navigate to the detail view. Here is my ListingView code:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(viewModel.tableViewItems) { contact in
            NavigationLink(destination: ContactDetailView(viewModel: ContactDetailViewModel(contact: contact))) {
                Text(contact.fullName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I found online and it works. But I found out that the view and the viewModel of the destination were getting initialised just after the List is populated, without even selecting. Is this correct or am I not understanding something properly?

Comment: This is `ContactDetailViewModel(contact: contact)` a call of constructor, and there are `ContactDetailView(viewModel: ContactDetailViewModel(contact: contact))` calls of two constructors, so how do you think what's going on here?

Comment: The ContactDetailView requires ContactDetailViewModel which in turn requires Contact. It's using MVVM architecture.

Comment: I'm about different... `body` is just calculable property, a function call, so once it is called then everything within it executed (taking into account conditional branching of course), so *selecting* does not matter actually here. Yes, it is correct - everything constructed at once, just take this into account and don't put any heavy calculations into views `init()`. But... constructed does not mean presented... so `body` of each constructed view will be called *only* when it will be needed to present that view.